# Enter Key in Find dialog makes new line instead of jumping to the first result

Tags: visual-studio-code

After hitting CTRL+F (or CMD+F) my find-dialog opens in the top right corner with focus on the input.

Usually, after I enter the search term, I hit enter to jump to the first result. Unexpectedly, this creates a new line in the search input.

I tried looking in the settings, but no luck. I remember that it wasn't that way when I first installed VS Code.

How can I solve this, so that it jumps to the first found result?

Comment: I can replicate that issue if the `Find Next  - editor.action.nextMatchFindAction` command has been disabled.  Check if that is the case for you. Also run the `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` command from the Command Palette and report what command the `Enter` key is bound to when you have the find input focussed in the Find Widget.

Comment: Was your `editor.action.nextMatchFindAction` command keybinding disabled?

Comment: After months I've finally resolved this by setting this:
`{ "command": "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction", "key": ""}`
in keybindings.json - removing `-` from command and `enter` from key

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the shortcut broke after I imported the keymap from Android Studio.

To solve this, you want to have `enter` in `editor.action.nextMatchFindAction`:

```
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
  "when": "editorFocus && findInputFocussed"
}
```

Screenshot of the correct settings:

[image: Screenshot of correct settings]